# how would I view ntfs-style permissions on linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, ntfs

I mounted an ntfs external disk on Linux just for accessing its files (Also I installed a read/write ntfs driver). I noticed that the files on the drive are still using linux-style permissions instead of Windows ACLs, so system folders like `System Volume Information` are not hidden under Linux.

I know that these Linux permissions are stored as metadata in the file, but does Windows do something similar? or are the ACLs managed in the registry?

Comment: They're part of the filesystem, not the registry. [Where does Windows store ACLs and do ACLs follow a file from one machine to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839625/where-does-windows-store-acls-and-do-acls-follow-a-file-from-one-machine-to-anot)

Comment: Nice! I never saw that question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [NTFS-3G](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) driver, then there's an utility to view NTFS permissions on Linux. However, you got to be familiar with NTFS DACL (Discretionary Access Control List) format before you can read them comfortably. (NTFS DACL do not map pretty well with Unix's file modes, or at least the mapping is off by default in most Linux distributions.)

The utility is [**ntfs-3g.secaudit**](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/security-data-auditing/). But keep in mind that its output isn't neat—comparing with `icacls` in Windows Vista or later.

```
ntfs-3g.secaudit -v file
```

Try it.

Comment: What a coincidence! Just a few days ago I was trying to rename a few videos that had a colon in their filename, because Windows would not allow me to use those files. I thought about using my Scientific Linux 7 machine, and getting ntfs-3g from the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo. My network is sluggish so I want do download it manually. Do you know if ntfs-3g requires any additional packages?

Comment: Now moved here: http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/ntfssecaudit.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the last link provided by @bjd2385 is also dead now (returns an error). Apparently the info has been migrated to https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/Checking-Ownership-and-Permission-Data-in-an-NTFS-Volume